# How to pass additional parameters to a Spring Boot SpringApplication programatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I am trying to figure out how to set/override properties from a Spring Boot SpringApplication programatically when running the app.

By default, I know I can pass command line arguments to the boot application, but I want to embed the spring boot application in another java app, and executed from within the parent app.  I've included it as a dependency to my project.

In my Spring Boot application I have the following:

```
static public main(String [] args){
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Sync.class);
    app.setWebEnvironment(false);
    app.setShowBanner(false);
    app.run(args);
}
```

This allows me to set command line arguments, such as `--userName=Eric` etc.

Although I realize I can technically do the same programmatically and add `--userName=Eric` to my args[] array in code, I figured there must be another cleaner/neater way to pass an argument/property to my `app`.  But I cannot seem to find any other method in `SpringApplication` that allows me to set that type of value.

I'm looking for something that would allow me to do something like the following:

```
app.setProperty("username", "Eric");
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to set it in application.properties if you want to hardcode it already?

Comment: I've simplified the use case a little, but the parameters are configurable in the calling app, so hard coding an application.properties file is not something I'd want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need more control over the application that you are creating, you can use `SpringApplicationBuilder` and, in this case, its [`properties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#properties-java.lang.String...-) method. For example:

```
 new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties("foo=bar").run(args);
```

There are also variants that take `Properties` and `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not finding a way to modify the app arguments other than what you've suggested, but I would posit your use case fits external configuration:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

If you know the values you need ahead of time, I would think the application.config file is where they should live.  Then you can access them via @Value annotations etc.

Comment: That's just it.  I don't know their cases ahead of time.  The calling app is specifying the params.  I'm just trying to move the param from the command line to the execution call.