# How do you pass program arguments in a @SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a spring boot application.  I want to run it like this:

```
 java -jar myjar.jar inputFile outputFile
```

How do I write a `@SpringBootTest` for this?  I imagine that using `@SpringBootTest` would make Spring fail during startup because some of my code would say, "you need to provide an inputFile and outputFile".  Is there a way to pass program arguments when using a `@SpringBootTest`?

[I'm inferring from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36807196/61624) that I may have to use a SpringApplicationBuilder to do this.

I *thought* I had the answer but I was wrong.  This incorrect information may still be useful to some:

---

(*This information is wrong.  I think that some arguments can't be referred to in code as properties, but not all.  I still don't know how to get the application arguments in a `@SpringBootTest`*) I was confused because I didn't understand the terminology.  The annotation has a parameter for "properties".  I thought it was to point it at a property file, [but the documentation says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36807196/61624):

> Properties in form key=value that should be added to the Spring Environment before the test runs.

The other piece of the terminology puzzle is that what I called "program arguments" the Spring docs refer to as "properties".

This is some additional relevant documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-arguments

---

This is a workaround (not an answer).  You can do something like this:

```
private SpringApplicationBuilder subject;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    subject = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
}

@Test
public void requiresInputAndOutput() throws Exception {

    thrown.expect(IllegalStateException.class);
    subject.run();
}

@Test
public void happyPathHasNoErrors() throws Exception {

    subject.run(EXISTING_INPUT_FILE, "does_not_exist");
}
```

I don't like this very much.  It prevents me from using `@Autowired` elsewhere in my test.

Answer (score 10):

if your program arguments is

```
--arg1=val1
```

before springboot version 2.2.0
you can use

```
@SpringBootTest({"arg1=val1"})
```

after springboot 2.2.0
you can use

```
@SpringBootTest(args={"--arg1=val1"})
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  Out of the box, the `SpringBootContextLoader` (used by default with `@SpringBootTest`) [always runs your app without any arguments](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootContextLoader.java#L127).  However, you can provide your own bootstrapper, which can then in turn provide your own `SpringApplication` that gets called to run your test.  From there, you can override the `run(String... args)` method to provide whatever arguments you want.

For example, given a simple application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner app() {
        return args -> System.out.println(args.getOptionNames());
    }
}
```

You can inject test arguments with:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@BootstrapWith(RestartAppsTest.Bootstrapper.class)
class RestartAppsTest {

    static class Bootstrapper extends SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper {
        static class ArgumentSupplyingContextLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {
            @Override
            protected SpringApplication getSpringApplication() {
                return new SpringApplication() {
                    @Override
                    public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args) {
                        return super.run("--restart");
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<? extends ContextLoader> getDefaultContextLoaderClass(Class<?> testClass) {
            return ArgumentSupplyingContextLoader.class;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testRestart() {
        // 
    }
}
```

It's obviously a bit verbose, but it works.  You could clean it up and make a nicer/reusable bootstrapper that looked for your own annotation (or possibly reuse JUnit Jupiter's  `@Arguments`) that declared what arguments to supply (instead of hardcoding them).

Comment: I opened a PR to add support for this to `@SpringBootTest`.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/14823

Comment: Building off of this, you can actually just use `@SpringBootTest` and `@BootstrapWith`, no need to drop down to `@ContextConfiguration` and a superfluous (as of Spring Boot 2.1) `@ExtendWith`.

Answer (score 2):

For me working example is

```
@SpringBootTest(args ={"--env", "test"})
class QuickFixServerAppTest {

    @Test
    void loadContextTest() {
    }
}
```

is the same as passing the

```
--env test
```

argument when starting Spring

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class, args ={inputFile, outputFile})` if your app's main method looks a little different like

```java
public static void main(String[] args){ 
     SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Comment: How do you know, how the main method looks like?

Comment: it's just the main method in the Spring application

Comment: Yes, usually this is a main method of a Sping Boot application. But I think @Daniel has added his own code which checks the arguments somehow... So actually we can't know how to fix his problem.

Comment: We don't need to know what the main method looks like. `@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class, args ={inputFile, outputFile})` simulates the behavior that @Daniel was asking for where the SpringBootTest receives the args `inputFile` and `outputFile`

Answer (score 0):

Normally you're writing tests for your services; not the boot strapper. Spring Boot will pass command line parameters to your classes - perhaps using the @Value annotation, which in turn will be parameters to your service. Consider testing your services using the SpringRunner. Here's an example from my code base.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    Neo4jConfigTest.class,
    FdTemplate.class,
    FdServerIo.class,
    MapBasedStorageProxy.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"dev", "fd-auth-test", "fd-client"})
public class TestEntityLinks  {

@Autowired
private ContentModelService contentModelService;

@Autowired
private BatchService batchService;

@Test
public void doSomething () { ... }
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your answer, but I don't know how to take action on it.  Seems like you're saying, "Don't test this way.  Here's how you should test the *other* components of your app though."  In the context of my question, I feel my workaround is more helpful.

Comment: Maybe, but coding with Spring is easier when you follow the conventions. There is no need to build & run the application, for a test, in the way you're describing. SpringRunner will build the application context and let you autowire your services. Likewise @WebAppConfiguration is used to establish a testable web-server context.

Comment: I want to test that it errors on start up if you don't pass these command line arguments.

Comment: Have you looked at implementing CommandLineRunner for your SB app? You implement the run method and can have access to the args. HTH

Comment: Yeah, actually I implemented `ApplicationRunner`