Fetch command line argument to test method
I need to build a console application where I need to validate the input string for some conditions. The input string is the first command line argument.
It is given, we need to have proper structure in the project using build, project properties, write test cases etc. I used maven with spring boot.
When I am writing the test class, I am not understanding how to get command-line argument into test method as input argument.
public class checker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(checker.class, args);
        
        String input=args[0];
        
        //System.out.print(checker(input));
        
    }
    public String determineXml(String input) {
        
        int n=input.length();
        char[] array=input.toCharArray();
        
        List<String> leftTag=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> rightTag=new ArrayList<>();
        
        int current=0,start=0;
        int leftcount=0,rightcount=0;
        boolean isLeftTag=false,isRightTag=false;
        
        while(current<n) {
            
            if(current<n && array[current]=='<') {
                current++;
                
                if(array[current]=='/') {
                    isRightTag=true;
                    isLeftTag=false;
                    start=current+1;
                }
                else {
                    if(rightcount>0)
                        return "Invalid";
                    
                    isLeftTag=true;
                    isRightTag=false;
                    start=current;
                }
                
                while(current<n && array[current]!='>') {
                    current++;
                }
                
                if(current<n && array[current]=='>') {
                    if(isLeftTag) {
                        leftTag.add(input.substring(start, current));
                        leftcount++;
                    }
                    else {
                        rightTag.add(input.substring(start, current));
                        rightcount++;
                    }
                    current++;
                    
                }
            
            }
            
            else {
                while(current<n && array[current]!='<') {
                    current++;
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        if(leftcount!=rightcount)
            return "Invalid";
        
        int size=leftcount;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            int right=i;
            int left=size-1-i;
            
            if(!rightTag.get(right).equals(leftTag.get(left)))
                return "Invalid";
        }
        
        return "Valid";
        
    }

}


class TestCase {
    checker main=new checker();

    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("\n" + main.determineXml(str));
    }

}

Here I need first command line argument in str.
The way program is supposed to run from console-
> checker.exe "<Design><Code>hello world</Code></Design>"
Valid


Is this a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42377254/2308683

@OneCricketeer I think this is similar but too complex to understand. I am new to the framework

If you want to test the checker. please use the main method instead of writing a test method.

@YaohuiWu   it is given in the task that we have to write junit test cases. I understand I can test it from the main method itself

@Vibhav So which method of checker do you want to test? If it is determineXml, I think it does't matter where you got the argument from a constant string or command line.

@YaohuiWu I need to test determineXML method. I have now added the complete code in description

@YaohuiWu I got it from your comment that it won't matter but didn't undetstand. Can you please give a code snippet how it should work?

@Vibhav Just add a line to the test() method after the first '{':
String str = "hello world";

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You seem to be unaware that JUnit tests are not usually run from the command line, but instead they are run from Maven, Gradle or your IDE. In any case, even if they are run from the command line, they don't take command-line parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line for more info.


used maven with spring boot.

Remove Spring Boot. It has its own way of handling CLI arguments and won't help you write tests. In fact, separate your business logic completely from any framework (although, I would highly recommend using an actual XML parsing library; your tests break for <!-- / --> comments) and use core Java concepts.
Also create separate files in src/test/java folder for unit tests, and use assertions, not print statements
public class Main {
    public static main(String[] args) {
        Checker c = new Checker();
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println(c.determineXml(args[0]));
        } else {
            System.err.println("Argument expected");
        } 
    } 
}

static class Checker {
  public String determineXml(String input) { }
}

public class TestChecker {

    private Main.Checker = new Main.Checker();

    @Test
    public void testDetermineXml() {
        String input =  "...";  // TODO: consider a parameterized test 
        assertEquals("Valid", this.checker.determineXml(input));
    } 
}

If you must use Spring, please check the documentation for your use case - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/testing/spring-boot-applications.html#testing.spring-boot-applications.using-application-arguments

Why don't you simulate this process by defining the arguments inline and calling the function?
class TestCase {

    @Test
    void test() {
        String[] args = {"<Design><Code>hello world</Code></Design>"};

        checker main = new checker();
        String result = main.determineXml(args[0]);
        assertEquals("Valid", result);
    }

}

When you move to production, you can simply pass the arguments via command line, but for testing purposes, in my opinion, this is much easier to work with.

I am new to frameworks. I understood you declared string arguments inline for testing purpose. So would it automatically ask/take command-line argument when I run it from console?

When I run the program from console with string argument, it would automatically call the test method. Then wouldn't it take the already hard-coded string as input? Just want to clarify if I am thinking the right way

When you are running the program from the command line, you will have to change the logic so as to accept the command line arguments and process those rather than the args array declared here.

How to do that?

Spring Boot handles arguments differently than a typical Java app

@OneCricketeer I am new to the framework. I tried searching a lot. Would it be possible if you can give a code example how to achieve that?

@Vaibhav Spring Boot isn't required for what you're trying to test. It would be recommended to decouple your CLI argument handler from any framework. My comment was for Dimitar
